# Django page reloading too long

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have some issues with the reloading time in some page in Django, it takes too long.
I use debug_toolbar and shows me Browser timing request:  4 (+113577)
[image]

models.py

```py
class Subsidiary(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200, blank=False,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class SubBudget(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class SubBudgetOwner(models.Model):
    budget_owner = models.ForeignKey(Person, models.PROTECT, related_name="budgets_owned")
    sub_budget_owner = models.ForeignKey(Person, models.PROTECT, related_name="sub_budgets_owned")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["id"]
        unique_together = (("budget_owner", "sub_budget_owner"),)
        verbose_name = "Budget Owner"  # Title on the maint page for this table
        verbose_name_plural = "Budget Owners"  # Title for the navbar navigation

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.budget_owner) + " - " + str(self.sub_budget_owner)


class Combination(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    subsidiary = models.ForeignKey(Subsidiary, verbose_name="Subsidiary", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, verbose_name="Department", on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    sub_budget = models.ForeignKey(SubBudget, verbose_name="Sub Budget", on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    budget_owner = models.ForeignKey(SubBudgetOwner, verbose_name="Budget Owner & Sub Budget Owner", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    def __str__(self):
        return (f"{self.subsidiary} {self.department} {self.sub_budget} {self.budget_owner}")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["id"]
```

My views.py

```py
class CombinationListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Combination
    template_name = "budget/combination_list.html"
```

combination_list.html

```
{% for combination in object_list %}
     <tr>
          <td>{{ combination.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ combination.subsidiary }}</td>
          <td>{{ combination.department }}</td>
          <td>{{ combination.sub_budget }}</td>
          <td>{{ combination.budget_owner }}</td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I think maybe all the ForeignKeys do it so slow...

What can I do to improve it?

Comment: Show your `combination_list.html`

Comment: I added, thanks.
What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution.
I added queryset function (CombinationQuerySet) and it makes a magic

In my model.py:

```
class CombinationQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def fast(self):
        return self.select_related(
            "subsidiary",
            "department",
            "sub_budget",
            "budget_owner__budget_owner",
            "budget_owner__sub_budget_owner",
        )

class Combination(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    subsidiary = models.ForeignKey(Subsidiary, verbose_name="Subsidiary", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, verbose_name="Department", on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    sub_budget = models.ForeignKey(SubBudget, verbose_name="Sub Budget", on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    budget_owner = models.ForeignKey(SubBudgetOwner, verbose_name="Budget Owner & Sub Budget Owner", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    objects = CombinationQuerySet.as_manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return (f"{self.subsidiary} {self.department} {self.sub_budget} {self.budget_owner}")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["id"]
```

my view.py (added the line: queryset = Combination.objects.fast()):

```
class CombinationListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Combination
    template_name = "budget/combination_list.html"
    queryset = Combination.objects.fast()
```

I saw it improved the page loading much faster (1 sec even less)!

Answer (score 1):

You are making 11k queries in this page. This takes 46 seconds. You should start by lower the number of requests.

You should start by checking if you can use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) or [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to improve the requests generated by your template.

Comment: how can I do that? do I need to change my model.py and my view?

Answer (score 0):

def fast(self): is really helpful and used in my app.
return self.select_related was because a foreign keys and make it faster in the quary